# How to call destructor after response in php?

Tags: php, apache, optimization, exit

I have a chat bot which save some data into db which user is sending. I want to save it to db (a slow network call) after sending response to the user.

I could do that in Python Tornado but I havent been able to do it PHP Apache.

user sends input as request -> we process it -> we send output to user as response -> **then we wish to store data**

```
  class A
  {
      function __construct()
        {
          echo "Hello World";
        }
      function __destruct()
        {
          sleep(15); //I want this to happen after response is being send
        }
      function calc()
        {
          echo "Progress World";
        }
  }
```

Comment: And what's your question now? There is a magic method `__destruct()` for classes.

Comment: is __destruct() called after response has been send?

Comment: Whether something is processed after you sent something only depends on whether you terminate your script afterwards or not. Anyways: use output buffering for this. Then you can still react when storing the data fails.

Comment: @arkascha the code is in index.php So I think it is called by apache on request n terminated by apache after response. Isn't?

Comment: `__destruct()` gets called if the scripts end with success and also if it ends with an error or the object gets unsetted.

Comment: @TiMESPLiNTER __destruct() is called before response is send and thus do not meet the objective. Functionality implemented in it would effect response time.

Comment: Why should the http server suddenly and spontanously kill your php script just because you sent out some data? No! The script will continue to run, there are only two exceptions: 1. you explicitly stop execution (for example by using the `return` statement inside your code) or 2. when you specify a response length, send the response and the _client_ drops the connection. You can still have your script run on by using phps `ignore_client_abort()` function for such cases. But as said: output buffering would make sense here in my eyes. Generate the response and only send it when all is done.

Answer (score 0):

`__destruct` is called upon object deletion, the object being out of scope, or normal script ending. If the script isn't terminating normally but killed, the destructor may not be called at all.

If you just want to do cleanup task at specific points and ensure them being processed use the PHP  5.5-introduced [`finally` clause](https://www.php.net/exceptions)

A  `__destruct` example from the PHP site:

```
<?php
class my_class {
  public $error_reporting = false;

  function __construct($error_reporting = false) {
    $this->error_reporting = $error_reporting;
  }

  function __destruct() {
    if($this->error_reporting === true) $this->show_report();
    unset($this->error_reporting);
  }
?>
```

See the [PHP Documentation on destructors](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php). I hope this helps.

Comment: Would __destruct be called after response? Wont apache terminate the index.php code no sooner response is send?

Comment: @dragosrsupercool how apache knows when all response is sent? Unless script terminates nobody can tell whether whole response is sent

Comment: __destruct is called before response is send. Activities done is it affects response time.

Answer (score 0):

PHP's garbage collector and object destruction are automatic processes managed by the runtime, so you don't have direct control over when destructors are called.
You can add your cleanup function in `finally` block of exception handling.

```
try{
 // your code
}catch(Exception $e){
 // exception handling
}finally{
 //perform cleanup task or destructor here
}
```